# Difference between num_threads vs. omp_set_num_threads vs OMP_NUM_THREADS

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I am quite confused about the ways to specify the number of threads in parallel part of a code.
I know I can use:

1. the enviromental variable OMP_NUM_THREADS
2. function omp_set_num_threads(int)
3. num_threads(int) in `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NB_OF_THREADS)`

What I have gathered so far the first two are equivalent. But what about the third one?
Can someone provide a more detailed exposition of the difference, I could not find any information in the internet regarding the difference between 1/2 and 3.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`OMP_NUM_THREADS` and `omp_set_num_threads()` are not equivalent. The environment variable is only used to set the initial value of the *nthreads-var* ICV (internal control variable) which controls the maximum number of threads in a team. `omp_set_num_threads()` can be used to change the value of *nthreads-var* at any time (outside of any parallel regions, of course) and affects all subsequent parallel regions. Therefore setting a value, e.g. `n`, to `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is equivalent to calling `omp_set_num_threads(n)` before the very first parallel region is encountered.

The algorithm to determine the number of threads in a parallel region is very clearly described in the [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu35.html) that is available freely on the OpenMP website:

> **if** a `num_threads` clause exists
>
> **then let** *ThreadsRequested* be the value of the `num_threads` clause expression;
>
> **else let** *ThreadsRequested* = value of the first element of *nthreads-var*;

That priority of the different ways to set *nthreads-var* is listed in the *ICV Override Relationships* part of the specification:

> The `num_threads` clause and `omp_set_num_threads()` override the value of the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable and the initial value of the first element of the *nthreads-var* ICV.

Translated into human language, that is:

- `OMP_NUM_THREADS` (if present) specifies initially the number of threads;
- calls to `omp_set_num_threads()` override the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS`;
- the presence of the `num_threads` clause overrides both other values.

The actual number of threads used is also affected by whether dynamic team sizes are enabled (*dyn-var* ICV settable via `OMP_DYNAMIC` and/or `omp_set_dynamic()`), by whether a thread limit is imposed by *thread-limit-var* (settable via `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT`), as well as by whether nested parallelism (`OMP_NESTED` / `omp_set_nested()`) is enabled or not.

Comment: When you say *"the presence of the num_threads clause overrides both other values"*, what is the scope? Is `num_threads` program wide, or is it just for the OMP block? If `num_threads` is program wide, then how do we change the thread count for just an OMP block?

Comment: @jww, the scope of the `num_threads` clause is the region to which it is applied.

Comment: I think it's also important to note that the `num_threads` clause completely avoids the lock that gets used by `omp_set_num_threads`. If you're working on code that is performance/timing critical, use `num_threads`.

Answer (score 10):

Think of it like scope.  Option 3 (num_threads) sets the number of threads for the current team of threads only.  The other options are global/state settings.  I generally don't set the number of threads and instead I just use the defaults.  When I do change the number of threads it's usually only in special cases so I use option three so that the next time I use a parallel team it goes back to the global (default) setting.  See the code below.  After I use option 3 the next team of threads goes back to the last global setting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            printf("%d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
        }
    }
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            printf("%d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            printf("%d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            printf("%d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
        }
    }       
}
```

4
8
2
8